# Is it possible to block default browser in Android mobile?

Tags: android, security, browser

Android phone comes with a default browser. Is there any possibility to block default browser?

I would like to develop a mobile browser with more security like black listing some sites, blocking unwanted sites using key word based access, storing user credentials in a secure vault and so on. With this, we can implement almost all sort of security breeches.

Or otherwise when you open your default browser it must kill the app and it must invoke my browser app. I need to enforce more security instead of writing a browser plug in or firewall for the default app.

Is there any similar app before? Can any one give some hint or provide me a link to refer.

Thanks.

Comment: I hope 'we can implement almost all sort of security breeches' was worded wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Can't you select your browser as default in settings? Won't that do the job? If you want to remove the default browser then you can always root and use root uninstaller.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to block your default browser.You can monitor the running process and whenever you get browser you can kill it by killBackgroundProcess of ActivityManager class.If you want to see an application you can see Advanced Task killer application.

Anyways, I didn't find ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED broadcast work in the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could try uninstalling the default web browser using adb shell (no root required). An explanation on how to do this can be found here: 
https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/

When doing this, be aware of the possible harm you can do to your device when uninstalling the wrong app/service/worker.